# Do the psaserv and psacln groups have particular meanings?

Tags: linux, user-groups

I'm not well versed in server admin stuff, but I notice the user groups psaserv and <strike>psacli</strike> psacln come up all the time on different systems.  I assume these group names are commonly used for a particular purpose/role.  Is that true?  Like what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These groups are created by Plesk, a common server administration panel that is generally used on web servers hosting websites.

The `psaserv` group is used for the server-side management scripts and also for parent-level directories that should not be shared between different websites.

I have not seen a `psacli` group, but on normal Plesk installations there is the alternative `psacln`. This group is used for client-side files, such as all of the files held within a website.

Comment: I'll point out that apache is a member of both groups. These are a good way to make files accessible to the apache user.